# How do you get XML data from other websites who do not provide their API publicly to use in your own ios applications?

Tags: xml

How do you get XML data from other websites to use in your own ios applications? The website who do not have any public API available for use.
I am new to xcode and objective c please explain in little detail.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write your own service that scrapes the site for information, converts it to XML, and then provides your API.  This may be against the site's terms and conditions; you would have to confirm with the content owners.

This is not ideal because you would have to constantly update your scraper if the site changed their layout; or the site could simply block your scraper from their servers.

The best solution is to talk to the content owners and work out a way to license their data. They may have an API that is not public.